# How to fix TypeError: can only concatenate str (not list) to str?

Tags: python

```
nums = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

firstNum = int(input("What's the first number of your list?"))

lastNum = int(input("What is your last number of your list?"))

odds = []
evens = []

for num in range(firstNum, lastNum):
   if num % 2 == 0:
     evens.append(num)
   
else:
   odds.append(num)
  
print("Numbers of evens:" + evens)
print("Number of odds:" + odds)
```

I am trying to filter evens and odds in a tuple but I get the error and I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Are you sure that the indentation of your `else` statement is correct? Right now it belongs to the `for` statement, not to the `if` statement. I think this is not what you intended.

Comment: And apart from that: `evens` and `odds` are lists. You cannot add a string and a list with `+`. What do you actually want to print? The whole list (i.e. all elements)? The count of the elelements (i.e. the length of the list)? Or something else? ― Please specify what the *expected* output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
print("Numbers of evens:", evens)
print("Number of odds:", odds)
```

Like this you are not adding strings (`"Numbers of evens:"`) and a list (`evens`).

Full code:

```
firstNum = 1#int(input("What's the first number of your list?"))
lastNum = 9#int(input("What is your last number of your list?"))

odds = []
evens = []

for num in range(firstNum, lastNum):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(num)
       
    else:
        odds.append(num)
  
print("Numbers of evens:", evens)
print("Number of odds:", odds)
```

Output:

```
Numbers of evens: [2, 4, 6, 8]
Number of odds: [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Oh thank it works, however it will still sometimes put even numbers in the odd list. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: It works if you get the indentation right. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh thank you that works, is there a way to get the 9 in the odd list too since 1 is there too

Comment: In Python, range(firstNum, lastNum) goes to lastNum - 1, so range(1, 9) gives [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. If you want the maximum value to be included, you have to do `range(firstNum, lastNum + 1)`.

Comment: Oh never mind in the for loop I added a + 1 after the “lastNum.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `print("Number of evens:" + evens)` you are trying to concatenate a string with a list, that's not possible. Instead, you should convert evens to string with `str(evens)`, or use a `print()` separating with comma instead of concatenation

Comment: Thank you it worked, however it still sometimes puts a even number in the odd list. Like if I make the range from 1 to 9, it will do 2,4,6,8 in the even list and put 8 in the odd list without also putting 1,3,5,7,9